# Extract all p and a tags from each div with a certain class

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I have a webpage with the following structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There's additional content in the page, but for the purposes of this question, it's irrelevant (kind of).

What I'd like to do is extract the `<a>` and `<p>` elements from each div with the class `title`. I've rolled around numerous ways to do this (`simple-html-dom`, `xPath`, Regex etc.) but due to my limited knowledge of PHP I'm struggling to understand and a little push in the right direction will probably help me hugely.

So my question is, what would you use? And could you give me an example of how you would use it. It doesn't have to be fool proof, as long as I get the idea then I'll do the rest.

Thanks.

Comment: please try this. It may help you http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Please also post the code you have tried. Most of the solutions you mention (DOMXPath, etc.) have enough code samples in the documentation to get you started. FWIW, I would go for DOMXPath and DOMDocument -- simplehtmldom is also OK but has a few bugs, and simpleDOM is not as simple as the name suggests.

Comment: Using jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/o2joyq9j/1/

Comment: There's nothing there. If there *was* something there and you described what you wanted in terms of output, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @sanki the OP says nothing about javascript.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: That's why its been posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it solved as seen below. Not sure why it's been put on hold, since it was answered correctly and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `DOMDocument` in this particular case.

Here is a rough example:

```
$markup = "<html>
  <body>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <a></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = array();
$search = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]');
foreach($search as $node) {
    foreach($node->childNodes as $k => $child) {
        if(isset($child->tagName) && ($child->tagName == 'a' || $child->tagName == 'p')) {
            $data[$k][] = $child;
            // or $child->nodeValue if you want the innertext
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Or something like this if you're just expecting this structure to be like this always:

```
$search = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]');
foreach($search as $k => $node) {
    $a = $xpath->query('//a', $node)->item(0);
    $p = $xpath->query('//p', $node)->item(0);
    $data[] = array('a' => $a, 'p' => $p);
}
```

Comment: Excellent it works! Now I can see there are two arrays within another array, how would you iterate through both at the same time?

Comment: hi @Nesuke. im glad this helped. we'll if the structure is going to be the same, you could use the second answer i provided, i will be straightforward to get both elements

Comment: I've worked it out anyway :) I'm creating an SQL Server insert, but not there's single quotes in the data grr! Should be able to work it out from here. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Nesuke hehe, should escape those and it will work fine, sure man no prob im glad this helped

Comment: I used str_replace to replace any single quote with two singles (to escape them), but it's causing the value to be empty.

Comment: @Nesuke no thats not the proper way to escape them, use a function that will escape those. note: i'm not a sql server expert but you could do something like: `mssql_escape($somevalue)`

Comment: Hi, many thanks again for helping me on this. I realised I was passing the arguments for the replace through the wrong way around (doh!), SQL Server is the opposite to PHP for replacing strings. After I did this it worked fine and I've got all the stuff I needed in a table on my database. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nesuke im glad it went good in the end, youre welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can also use php
here is a little code to help

```
   <?php
     $filename="nameofhtmlfile.html"
   $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
   $new_contents = str_replace('<div class=\'title\'><a></a><p></p></div>', '<div class=\'title\'>         </div>', $contents);
  file_put_contents($filename, $new_contents);
    ?>
```

use this php script to read the content of the html file and use the php replace syntax to edit its content
               if your html file grows larger you might want to consider iterating instead of copying all to memory

```
        $f = fopen("file","r");
       if($f){
       while( !feof($f) ){
        $line = fgets($f,4096);
      if ( (stripos($line,"<div class=\'title\'><a></a><p></p></div>")!==FALSE) ){
        $line=preg_replace("<div class=\'title\'><a></a><p></p></div>","<div class=\'title\'>         </div>",$line);
      }
      print $line;
     }
   fclose($f);
   }
```